# Text overlapping each other in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text

I am just using flutter normally when I am using the expansion tile to create a page, some of the text starts to overlap each other.
But weirdly, it is only the first two text that will stick to each other, the others will work normally.
What could be the problem?
All of these are just a simple Text widget with a style using bodyText2 textTheme with a custom font which is google font Nunito

```
Column(
  children:[                      
    Text('     a  temperature higher than 37.5°C or more ',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(color: Colors.grey)),
    Text('     yellow  discharge or crustiness around the eyes  ',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(color: Colors.grey)),
    Text('     inflamed  puffy eyes, or red eyes (pink eye)  ',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(color: Colors.grey)),
    ]),
```

[text overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK4Kp.png)

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue . More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: does it happen for all project?

Comment: all of my projects have the same problem. I am using flutter 3.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason it is acting this weird...
It is because the text is from a word file, in which inside there contains some formatting which is not copied properly.
I retyped the words that have problem and its fixed